# Cut out transparency of a view to not capture onclick?

Tags: android

Say you have a view that is a circle or a balloon and you want have two layers of onClick or onTap capturing.

For example a mapView with a balloon over top.

The image has transparency to it on the left and right of the spike. Does anyone know of a way to cut out this transparency to not absorb the onClick and let it pass through to the mapview instead?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you know the dimensions of the ballon? If so then find out the left top of the ballon in the layout and then in the `onTouch` method find out the current co-ordinates where the touch event occured.

If this new touch co-ordinates are within the body of ballon then handle it otherwise just return `false` from the ballon's `onTouch` method. Now android should pass on the event to the underlying view which would be you mapView.

Comment: Great idea, I did not think of using the balloon's dimensions to determine the onTouch area. I will have to figure out a way to hopefully programically identify if the onTouch region is over a transparent portion of the balloon.